# Hartshorne's definition of Jacobian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Firstly, Hartshorne defines a curve as complete nonsingular scheme of dimension $1$ over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Now, on his way to defining the Jacobian variety of a curve, he defines $\operatorname{Pic}^\circ(X\times T)$ in the following way. Let $X$ be a curve over $k$. For any scheme $T$ over $k$, we define $\operatorname{Pic}^\circ(X\times T)$ to be the subgroup of $\operatorname{Pic}(X\times T)$ consisting of all invertible sheaves whose restriction to each fibre $X_t$ for $t\in T$ has degree $0$.

I have a doubt in the above definition. Since, there is no given map $f:X\rightarrow T$, what does $X_t$ even mean? My guess is that he is taking $X_t$ to be $(X\times T)_t$ for the projection morphism $p:(X\times T)\rightarrow T$. Is that correct?

Assuming my percieved definition of $X_t$ is correct, I have the following question. $X_t$ is defined over $\operatorname{Spec}k(t)$ an $k(t)$ need not be an algebraically closed field. In that case does he take the definiton of degree of a divisor (or line bundle) in the same manner as he did in the algebaicaly closed case? I ask this because he assumes the field to be algebraically closed for most major results relating a curve and its divisors. I doubt all of them will continue to hold if the ground field is not algebraically closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your definition of $X_t:=(X\times T)\times_T \operatorname{Spec} k(t)$ is correct. For the definition of degree, there are several equivalents ways: you can either base change to the algebraic closure of $k(t)$ and compute the degree there, or note that because $X_t$ is smooth for every closed point $x$ the $O_x$ is a d.v.r and hence you can define $v_x(f)$ for the function $f\in K(X_t)$ which defines your divisor. then the degree would be $\Sigma [ k(x):k(t)]v_x(f)$. or you can define it as $$\deg(\lambda)=\Sigma \dim_{k(t)}\lambda_{\{x\}}$$ where $\lambda_{\{x\}}$ is $\lambda_x/m_x\lambda_x$.

you can also define $\operatorname{Pic}^0X$ as the connected component of $\operatorname{Pic} X$ containing the $O_X$.but I think for this definition you have to know that $\operatorname{Pic} X$ is representable by a scheme.

Comment: Thank a lot. That really helps